# How does the carriage return works in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, time

I'm doing countdown following the steps of a Youtube video but there's one thing I don't understand and it's the use of the carrage return in the line `print (time_left + '\r', end = '')` How `\r` works with end = '' to be able to erase the same line and write on it again? Because if I only writ `\r` the numbers appear in a new line.

```
while True:
     uin = input('')
     try:
          when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
          break
     except:
          print('That\'s not a number')
     while when_to_stop > 0:

          m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60) 
          h, m = divmod(m, 60)
          when_to_stop = when_to_stop - 1
          time_left = str(h).zfill(2)+ ':' + str(m).zfill(2) + ':' + str(s).zfill(2)
          print(time_left + '\r',  end = '')
          time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @L3viathan: That's a complete answer, may as well make it one.

Answer (score 0):

`print` prints all of its arguments, seperated by the keyword argument `sep`, terminated by the argument `end`:

```
>>> print(1, 2, 3, sep="+", end="=\n")
1+2+3=
```

By default, `sep` is a space, and `end` is `"\n"`; a line feed. By doing `end=''`, you prevent this line feed, such that the carriage return can move the cursor to the beginning of the line.

---

If you only do `print("\r")`, a carriage return *and* a line feed will be printed. This is in practice identical to just doing `print()`; printing nothing but a newline.

Comment: So `\r` only moves the cursor to the beginning of the line but it is `end = ' ' ` that erase all the line?

Comment: `end=' '` (with one space) erases exactly one character. If you print more spaces, it'll erase more of the line. If you print other content, it'll overwrite the line. Think of the carriage return (without line feed) of an old type-writer, except that any keypress first paints the spot white before printint a character.

Comment: So `end = ''` without space erase all the line automatically? But if I write: `a = 0
for a in range (5):
  print('Banana' + '\r', end = '')` it gives `nana`. Sorry for all the questions I'm quite new in Python.

Comment: @KIRA Do you happen to be on Windows? Because on my computer, that just prints "Banana". (Side note: You don't need to declare `a = 0` before the loop.)

Comment: Yes, I do. I write it on repl.it